# Test Page failed to print, Access denied

Tags: windows-vista, printer

**"Test page failed to print. Would you like to view the print troubleshooter for assistance? Access Denied."**

One of my friend is getting this error while trying to print the test page using my Epson Stylus SX235W.
while trying to print a page, it is giving error,
"printer can not print the page" digonose problem"

tried googling and searching in superuser but not getting the solution, help needed.

> Using a laptop computer (Fujitsu simens ) and OS : WINDOWS VISTA.
>   Logged in through admin account.The printer is connected through a usb
>   cable, i tried reinstalling the drivers twice (through web installer and through CD),  changing the ports,
>   restarting the print spooler services, deleted the files from
>   windows/system32/spool/printers,still getting the same error,and i am
>   on remote control with the users computer.

**Thanks a ton in advance.**

Comment: How is he connecting to the printer?

Comment: connected through a usb cable, i tried reinstalling the drivers, changing the ports, restarting the print spooler services, deleted the files from windows/system32/spool/printers.....still getting the same error....and i am on remote control with the users computer....

Comment: I'm assuming his user is an admin.

Comment: I am sorry max to provide you the half info, yes it is admin only. and i tried disabling UAC as well once.

Comment: Are you using the drivers from the Epson web site? http://www.epson.co.uk/Store/Printers-and-All-in-Ones/Epson-Stylus-SX235W/Drivers-Support#

Comment: i tried once downloading from the URL you said, and once i tried installing the drivers from scratch using the CD supplied with the printer, same error....

Comment: @Anonymous did you find the solution to this problem? I have the same one. First the problem was that I could not install x86 drivers to share on x64 but that is solved now. But now I'm having the problem also of the **Access Denied** screen.